# Navbar Responsive with Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am looking references or some way to make a responsive **Navbar** in Angular 5, if it's necessary to use **Bootstrap** and it's the best way or if there is any option not to use Bootstrap.

Attached example image:

[image]

Right now I'm using tabs, but it's something I'm willing to change if necessary:

```
<mat-toolbar role="heading" aria-label="navigation">

  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <h1 class="mat-display-1">{{ title }}</h1>
    <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
        <a mat-tab-link
           *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
           [routerLink]="link.path"
           routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
           [active]="rla.isActive">
            {{link.label}}
        </a>
    </nav>
    <!-- Mobile Button Nav -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></span>
    </button>

    <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the toolbar from Angular Material, which has a toolbar component (https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview)

To make your site (including toolbar) responsive, use the Flex Layout library https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki

Comment: Exact I use the toolbar component, but not working responsive like the image. Just update the code complete in the question.

Comment: thanks with your response I found this: https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/responsive-navbar-angular-flex-layout/

Comment: @yorchp link seems to be dead

Comment: @yorchp Managed to dig the github link from a cached version of that post: https://github.com/MainaWycliffe/Responsive-Navbar-with-Angular-Material-and-Angular-Flex-Layout/tree/master